# How to count Booleans in MongoDB with aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Documents are stored with the following fields:

```
_id:
NumberofChildren: Integer
OwnsAHome: Boolean
Income: Integer
```

I need to use the aggregation framework to sort by number of children so the output is something like this:

```
Number of Children: 3
Number of People: some value, say 17
Number of People who own a home: some value less than 17 which is a sum of the number of true Booleans
Average income: some value
```

How would I do this in  **MongoDB with aggregation** , especially in regards to counting the number of times the `Boolean OwnsAHome`, is `true`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I followed the @eri suggestion using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).

Given the data:

```
campaign | flags.click | flags.removed
c1       | true        | false
c1       | true        | true
c2       | false       | false
```

with:

```
Contact.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$campaign",
                countClick: {
                    $sum: { $cond: ["$flags.click", 1, 0] }
                },
                countRemoved: {
                    $sum: { $cond: ["$flags.removed", 1, 0] }
                },
            }
        }
    ]
).exec();
```

I will get the output:

```
campaign | countClick | countRemoved
c1       | 2          | 1
c2       | 0          | 0
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. There is no need for an additional projection stage as suggested in the answer from the 2013.

Answer (score 19):

The `$project` phase is your friend in the pipeline by allowing you to create new fields which have different types and values than original fields.

Consider this projection which uses `$cond` to use one value when something is true and another one when it's false:

{ $project : { numWhoOwnHome : { $cond : [ "$OwnsAHome", 1, 0 ] } } }

If you now do a `$group` with `{$sum : "$numWhoOwnHome"}` your result will be the number of people who had OwnsAHome set to true.

Comment: don't forget to add to $project for every field you want to include "fieldName:1" otherwise the only thing to come out of $project will be the _id field and this new calculated field.

Comment: `{'$group':{.... {count: { $sum: {$cond : [ "$closed", 1, 0 ] }}...}` $cond works in $group since 3.2 version

Answer (score 0):

(as a follow up to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682466/13373637))
You may even use [`$toInt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) instead of `$cond`

```js
db.Contact.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$campaign",
                countClick: {
                    $sum: { $toInt: "$flags.click" }
                },
                countRemoved: {
                    $sum: { $toInt: "$flags.removed" }
                },
            }
        }
    ]
)
```